# Powershell open session to 365 - syntax error

Tags: windows, powershell

I just have no idea how this happens.
im trying to write a script where admin would be able to do this:
./run.ps1 "muzi@puzi.com" .\list.txt
list.txt would have 365 shared mailboxes names.
the script will then take muzi@puzi.com and give him full access and sendAs permissions in those mailboxes.
it works good when i go line by line but for some reason when its all in the script i get very weird sytax error (even if i comment the line of the error i still get error there)

```
#./run "muzi@puzi.com" .\filename.txt

#Get-Credentials for 365 admin and open session
$O365Cred = Get-Credential
$O365Session = New-PSSession –ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell -Credential $O365Cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -force
Import-PSSession $O365Session

$user = $args[0]
$filename = $args[1]
$list = gc -Path ".\$filename"

foreach ($line in $list){
   Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "$line" -user "$user" -AccessRights FullAccess
   Add-RecipientPermission -Identity "$line" -AccessRights SendAs -Trustee $user -Confirm:$false
}
```

The error is:
[image]

Comment: `-Confirm $false` ?

Comment: try this ==>  Add-RecipientPermission -Identity "$line" -Trustee $user -AccessRights SendAs -Confirm:$false         <===

Comment: nope still same error, even if i comment the line

Comment: can you try foreach line in list wrtite host $line what is the value ? if i use my code  Add-RecipientPermission sharedmailboxusername -Trustee userusername -AccessRights SendAs -Confirm:$False works fine,

Comment: i see #./run "muzi@puzi.com" .\filename.txt muzi@puzi.com without "   ./run muzi@puzi.com .\filename.txt

Comment: Is file `list.txt` correct or does that have an opening quote withiout a closing one?

Comment: list.txt has a few mailboxes names, the script should run without the ".\" , again, weird thing is: if i manualy enter each line to powershell it would be fine, for what is saw this line could be the one causing the problem "$O365Session = New-PSSession –ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell -Credential $O365Cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection", but again i dont know why, its a normal session to 365

Comment: Do you ever `Remove-PSSession -Session $O365Session`  or make sure you have no sessions before creating a new one with `Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession`?

Comment: I had 4 session opened that seems to what caused the problem

Answer (score 0):

Found it, had 4 sessions already open